# Executar requisição ao mudar valor em uma select

Tags: javascript, html, html5, html-select, jquery-select2

Não estou conseguindo executar a função ao mudar o valor do select, segue o código abaixo.

***index.php***

```html
<div class="input-group m-2">

        <!-- Combo Estados !-->
        <div class="input-group-prepend ml-3">
            <label class="input-group-text" for="cmb_estado_site">Estado</label>
        </div>
        <select class="custom-select" id="cmb_estado_site"></select>

        <!-- Combo Cidade !-->
        <div class="input-group-prepend ml-3">
            <label class="input-group-text" for="cmb_cidade_site">Cidade</label>
        </div>
        <select class="custom-select" id="cmb_cidade_site">
            <option selected="TODAS" >TODAS</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

***function.js***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#cmb_estado_site').click(function () {
        var estado = $('#cmb_estado_site').val();
        $.post('/lib/php/function.php',{action:'load-cidade', estado:estado},function (data) {
            $('#cmb_operadora_site').html(data);
        });
    });
}
```

o retorno da requisição post está correto, testei pelo postman, pelo debug não está entrando na função, alguém poderia me informar o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Mostra como é o formato da resposta do $.post, (o que aparece se eu der um console.log(data) dentro do método `done `) para que a gente possa construir uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: Consegui resolver, o erro estava na forma como eu carregava a pagina, estava pegando de outro arquivo o código destas combos, isto depois de já ter carregado o script, por isso acho que não estava acionando o evento, mas obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o `change()` ao invés do `click()`

---

### EDIT

Como apontado nos comentários pelo José Guilherme Oliveira, o ID que recebe os dados é `#cmb_operadora_site`, mas aparentemente deveria ser `#cmb_cidade_site`

Comment: E o ID que recebe os dados é #cmb_operadora_site, mas não deveria ser #cmb_cidade_site?

Comment: exatamente José Guilherme Oliveira, já mudei tantas vezes esse código que até na hora de copiar copiei errado.

```javascript
$('#cmb_estado_site').change(function () {
        var estado = $('#cmb_estado_site').val();

        $.post("/lib/php/function.php", {action: "load-cidade", estado: estado})
            .done(function( data ) {
                $('#cmb_operadora_site').html(data);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "Ocorreu um erro!" );
            });
    });
```
mesmo desta maneira não está funcionando

Comment: parece não estar entrando na função, coloquei um breakpoint dentro da função e ele não está sendo acionado

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo você usar o método `done()` para usar o dado vindo do seu endpoint e também usar o método `fail()` para tratar algum possível erro que possa ocorrer, como um erro de conexão. Além disto, troque o listener de `click()` para `change()`. Faça assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cmb_estado_site').change(function () {

    $.post("/lib/php/function.php", {action: "load-cidade", estado: estado})
        .done(function( data ) {
            $('#cmb_operadora_site').html(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "Ocorreu um erro!" );
        });
    });
}
```